# How to make an identifier for some list items?

Tags: flutter, list, dart, key

I have a small list containing text, I would like some elements of this list to have the same ID

I tried to use GlobalKey, but I got an error

```
  final idKey = GlobalKey();

  final textList = <int, String>{
    0: 'Text', idKey
    1: 'Text',
    2: 'Text', idKey
    3: 'Text',
    4: 'Text', idKey
    5: 'Text',
    6: 'Text'
  };
```

Comment: `textList` is `map` rather than a `list`. What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

The textList that you've created is actually a Map, where the int represents a UNIQUE key by which you access the data (String in your example).

To solve your problem i would create a model class and create a list that is made up of that model

Example:

```
class MyModel {
   String data;
   bool isBold;

   MyModel(this.data, this.isBold);
}
```

```
List<MyModel> textList = [
MyModel('Text', true);
MyModel('Text', false);
MyModel('Text', true);
];
```

In the example above, we can see which elements of the list should be bold.

Of course, you can change the isBold variable with whatever you like or add more variables for a more specific definition.

If you really have to stick to having a Map, maybe you can make the Key a String instead of an int and give the key values like '0-same', '1', '2-same', etc. **But I don't recommend this solution**.

Happy coding!